# Is it possible to fetch an object without its relationships in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Let's say I have one entity "Person" with many attributes and one relationship "shoes" to another entity "Shoe".

The "Person" entity has thousands of "Shoe"s. I have sometimes the need to retrieve just the attributes of this person but I don't need to download all the shoes.

Is it possible to fetch only a "Person" without its relationship "Shoe"?

And consequently, is it possible to fetch the relationship "Shoe" once we already fetched the "Person"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is how Core Data works by default. If you use a fetch request to get a `Person`, then the returned object's `shoes` property is a “fault”. A fault is an empty shell. When you first try to access a fault's contents (its properties or, in the case of a collection, its member objects), the fault “fires” by loading its contents from the database.

Read about faults in the [*Core Data Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW1).

Comment: Thank! I actually overlooked Fault objects but didn't think (my bad) that it was how those relationships were loaded by default.